# SUB SELECT ORMLITE

Tags: android, ormlite

I would like to do a select with another select like this:
   `Select code, (Select Top 1 nameCode from Items where itemCode = code order by nameCode) from names`

I have looked for this information in the offical page but I can't find the solution.

Thank you